# User added in security group but email is not defined in AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, user-profile-service, active-directory-import

I added a user in SharePoint security group whose email was not defined in AD. There is a custom job that runs and email all users of that group. Since his email was not defined, no email was being sent to that user. User profile service is running.

Later on his email was updated in AD. Do I need to run full profile synchronization (or may be incremental) OR do I need to  remove that user from site collection, then add again and then his email will be available?

Comment: You can try removing the user from site permissions and then from site collection "User Information List", URL will be like: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx` and then add user again from site permissions. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by running following command to sync all users from AD into this website.

```
Get-SPUser -Web https://web-app-url | Set-SPUser -SyncFromAD
```